# Rails, JQuery, Ajax = Ajax params missing variable

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to access the JQuery Ajax call's data in my controller. Params does not hold this value, though it is supposed to. When I look at the request in Chrome, under Form Data I see the parameter's correct key-value pair, so I know JQuery is sending it.

How can I access this key-value pair that I am sending to the controller from the Ajax request?

```
#config/routes.rb
post 'projects/get_sum' => 'projects#get_sum', as: :get_sum

#from $ rake:routes
get_sum POST   /projects/get_sum(.:format)  projects#get_sum

#index.html.erb
<%= link_to 'Get sum', get_sum_path, id: "get_sum", method: :post , remote: true %>
<input id="input_val"></input>

#get_sum.js.erb
var $val = $('#input_val').val();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'projects/get_sum',
    data: { my_val: $val },
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log('Val is ' + $val); #returns correct input value
        console.log('Data is ' + data); #returns get_sum.html.erb
        $('#get_sum').hide().after("<%= 'sum: ' + @sum.to_s + '. Params: ' + params.inspect %>");
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log("Request error.");
    }
});

#projects_controller.rb
def get_sum
  @sum = Project.sum(:cost)
  @params = params # returns controller and action only
  @val = params[:my_val] #returns nil
end

#and in the rendered view, the following results:
sum: 95. Params: {"controller"=>"projects", "action"=>"get_sum"}
```

**UPDATE**

Well, it's becoming clear that this method is Doing It Wrong. My issue here is at least that I am calling the controller method first, which then triggers the .js.erb template, which then calls the HTML response of the same controller method. Which is why the parameters aren't being passed.

By using a link_to_function call instead, that triggers a JQuery Ajax call to the controller method that then loads the .js.erb template, I've made this scenario work. It feels clunky, and I'd still love to hear about a best practice for passing client-side variables to a server-side calculation, then ansynchronously rendering the result, **without using forms.**

Comment: Can you post your relevant routes? What happens if you do `p params` inside `get_sum`?

Comment: Updated with rake:routes relevant output.

Comment: 'p params' inside the controller get_sum method? I'm not sure what 'p params' means.

Comment: `p params` prints the params hash on the terminal console so you can analyze its contents during the request-response cycle.

Comment: Ah. I see some blog posts about it now. Still don't know how to use it, but when I dump params into the view it reads: {"controller"=>"projects", "action"=>"get_sum"}

Comment: Try encoding the data instead. `"my_val=" + $val`

Comment: No luck. I appreciate the suggestions though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `remote: true` in rails you don´t need to take care of the ajax call, because rails will do it for you. So it calls the controller, but instead of loading an html, it will load the `myMethod.js.erb`version of it.

So what you need to do, is change the HTML in your `index.html.erb` to use a form:

```
<%= form_tag get_sum_path, method: :post, id: "get_sum", remote: true do %>
    <%= label_tag :input_value, "Value:" %>
    <%= text_field_tag :input_value %>
    <%= submit_tag "Get sum" %>
<% end %>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Then if you print the params in the controller you will see the `"input_value"` added to it. So if you modify your `get_sum.js.erb` to have this:

```
$('#get_sum').hide();
$('#results').text("<%= @value %>");
```

And that should take care of the ajax request. Here is a link that might be helpful, and there´s also a RailsCast for this.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-and-ajax.htm

Also, I encourage you to use the rails debugger gem when trying to check for this things. https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger

Comment: Thank you, I'll start learning the debugger today, I've been putting it off. This solution makes sense, except that it's very limiting. What if I have information in an existing form I want to include or scattered information around a page? Do I just use pure JQuery and skip the Rails remote: true technique?

Comment: I managed to make a version of this work without forms (see updated question), but it doesn't feel very slick. Any insight into best practices for a technique without forms?

Comment: The `remote: true` from rails works the same as the jQuery in a simple way. And your `.js.erb` will be the same as your success callback. But if you want to do more complex stuff with AJAX or not use forms I would recommend using it directly with jQuery and not using the rails version. About best practices, I would recommend always use forms when you are interacting with the user, ad they are meant for input/output, and with this you should be able to use successfully the `remote: true` in 90% of the times.